# Having trouble querying the date in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select all interactions a user has done on a specific date with this query:

`SELECT * FROM tblInteractions WHERE date(ctime) = 2016-09-30 AND userID = 8`

But it fails, it brings back 0 results. I'm confused by this because this query:

`SELECT date(ctime) FROM tblInteractions WHERE userID = 8`

Returns:

```
date(`ctime`)   
2016-09-28     
2016-09-28
2016-09-28
2016-09-28
2016-09-28
2016-09-30
2016-09-30
```

What's wrong with my query? Is it a DB issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 SELECT * FROM tblInteractions WHERE date(ctime) = '2016-09-30' AND userID = 8
```

you are missing single quotes for date value

Answer (score 2):

If ctime db column is a date type, try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tblInteractions
WHERE date(ctime) = STR_TO_DATE('2016-09-30', '%Y-%m-%d') AND userID = 8
```

Answer (score 2):

Single quotes should resolve this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblInteractions 
WHERE DATE(ctime) = '2016-09-30' 
AND userID = 8
```